# Fetch Response.json Bad Escape Character Error

Tags: javascript, json, http, fetch

So, essentially I have a fetch that reaches out to an API, and then gets a JSON object in response. The problem is, the API will put an escape character for single quotes, for example `isn\'t`. That's throwing an error at JSON.parse(), so I want to manipulate the body of the response before calling response.json(). So here's my current code:

```js
    httpCallout(){
    fetch('/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=json', {method: "GET", cache: "no-cache"})
    .then(response => {
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const quote = data.quoteText;
      this.setState({
        quote: quote,
        author: data.quoteAuthor
      });
    });
    this.colorChange(rgb);
  }
```

The issue is whenever `response.json` is called with an escaped single-quote. I know I could just catch the error and do nothing, but I would much prefer a solution that lets me parse out the escaped single quote and still set my state from that call.

Essentially, what I'm looking to do, is take a response with a quoteText value of something like `"It\'s tiring isn\'t it?"` and parse that properly into `"It's tiring isn't it?"` before running response.json() so there isn't a `Bad escape character` error.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that JSON string

Comment: That's why I'm confused. When I GET via Postman, I get no error. It's only whenever I try to parse the JSON via response.json() or JSON.parse(response.body)

Comment: can't you add a `.catch(err => console.error(err))` to your promise flow and see what's going on

Comment: It would be worth adding the exact string you are receiving back from the server as part of the question, for us to be able to look over.

Comment: @balexandre I have the exact error, it's a JSON Bad Character Error on escaped single-quotes. I took out the catch block after I figured out what was happening.

Comment: @msbit It's a randomly selected quote string. Most strings work just fine, the only issue is whenever I receive a string that has a single quote in it because the server returns an escaped single quote `\'`, and whenever I try to parse the JSON, I get a Bad Escaped Character error.

Comment: @Pointy Btw after testing out strings with escaped single-quotes, it appears they aren't accepted as valid JSON strings.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. I'm guessing you're fetching from https://forismatic.com/en/api/. With the following: `{"quoteText":"You can\'t shake hands with a clenched fist.", "quoteAuthor":"Indira Gandhi", "senderName":"", "senderLink":"", "quoteLink":"http://forismatic.com/en/72b4eb8861/"}
`, I get `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 23 of the JSON data`. One answer is to file a bug report with the admin of the API as it's returning malformed responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unable to get the data provider to clean up their database or JSON encoding pipeline, you can clean up the returned text manually by:

- converting the `Response` to text using [`Body.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) (instead of [`Body.json()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json))
- replacing the offending bit with [`String.replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)
- explicitly parsing the JSON with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Putting that together in your function, we have:

```js
function httpCallout () {
  fetch('/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=json', { method: 'GET', cache: 'no-cache' })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      const cleanText = text.replaceAll("\\'", "'");
      return JSON.parse(cleanText);
    })
    .then(data => {
      const quote = data.quoteText;
      this.setState({
        quote: quote,
        author: data.quoteAuthor
      });
    });
  this.colorChange(rgb);
}
```

With the arguments to `String.replaceAll()` you need to escape the initial escaping `\` but not the single quote, hence it's:

`text.replaceAll("\\'", "'")`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had used the `Body.text()` earlier but forgot that it was then-able, and was trying to manipulate it as if it were a string. Definitely a big facepalm, but a lesson learned.